# Transferring Data between view controllers. While loading data from Parse. Data is transferred before Parse Query Populates the data

Tags: ios, parse-platform, loading, presentviewcontroller

I know how to transfer data between view controllers, but the data is being transferred before I am able to complete a parse query therefore the data is missing when the data is transferred between view controllers. 
The code I am using is as follows. with the first part related to the parse query and the last section detailing the sending of data. How can I get it so that the Data is successfully stored in phoneNUMBERS before it is passed to the new view? Because at the moment is is passed as NULL.

```
NSMutableArray *phoneNUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
    // Initialize table data
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendsAssociation"];
    //quesrys the class Friend asssociation to find when instances of "user" equal the
    //logged in user's username
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:usernamecontrol];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            if (objects.count == 0) {
                //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No User"
                                                                message:@"No user matches this username"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];








        }
        //if there is only one number matching the query

        if (objects.count >=1) {


            int i=0;

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSLog(@"%@", objects[i]);


                NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];





                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);

                [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
            }





            NSLog(@"%@", phoneNUMBERS[1]);




            //if there is more than one phonenumber matching the query as
            //the user to input the friends username
            //instead


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }}];

ContactTableViewController *contacts = [[ContactTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
contacts.user = usernamecontrol;
contacts.PHONENUMBERS = phoneNUMBERS;


[self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to put this part of code

```
ContactTableViewController *contacts = [[ContactTableViewController    alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil]; 
contacts.user = usernamecontrol;
contacts.PHONENUMBERS = phoneNUMBERS;

[self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Into the "succesful" part of completion block. i .e. right after

```
// Do something with the found objects
```

and before the next line with `if`.

Comment: I added it in there and It still returns null. when i log it out in the ContactTableViewController

Comment: @Daniel - this is correct answer in the sense that it addresses the most clearly incorrect part of the posted code.  The next likely cause is that the PHONENUMBERS property on ContactTableViewController is not declared strong.

Comment: @property(strong) NSMutableArray *PHONENUMBERS;   is how i have it declared in the ContactTableViewController. Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: wow I was just being stupid and log PHONENUMBERS out as NSLog(@"%", PHONENUMBERS); When i need to use _PHONENUMBERS   instead thank you guys for all your help i really appreciate it